# Using Laravel Mix in RTL

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am in case I have a public/assets folder that contains `style_en.css` and `style_ar.css` and is based on the app locale. Then, I can link the needed one to the blade.

But I want to try laravel mix to compile all CSS files for me. I did remove `bootstrap.min.css` and replaced it with the `css/app.css` file, and it works fine.

But I do not know how to have still the two RTL and LTR of the app work fine using mix with my `style_en.css` and `style_ar.css` files.

Any help?